# Как сгруппировать объект на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив:

```
[
    {"id":1, "name":"Melody 1", "artist":{"name": "Artist 1", "id":1}},
    {"id":2, "name":"Melody 2", "artist":{"name": "Artist 1", "id":1}}
]
```

Я хочу получить

```
[
    {"id":1, "name": "Artist 1", "content": [
        {"id":1, "name":"Melody 1"},
        {"id":2, "name":"Melody 2"}
    ]}
]
```

Перепробовал все варианты, которые удалось найти по js, но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу выполнять подобные операции?

Comment: Какие правила сборки? Почему именно так собрать?

Comment: @Other очевидно вроде по артисту сгруппированы?

Comment: У мелодии не может быть больше одного исполнителя? В реальном-то мире такое сплошь и рядом.

Comment: @teran, Если так, то это очень странная структура.

Comment: @Yaant В моей структуре исходных данных два исполнителя - это отдельный id. Так что, все ок

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
console.log(

    [
        {"id":1, "name":"Melody 1", "artist":{"name": "Artist 1", "id":1}},
        {"id":2, "name":"Melody 2", "artist":{"name": "Artist 1", "id":1}},
        {"id":3, "name":"Melody 3", "artist":{"name": "Artist 2", "id":2}},
    ]
    .reduce(
        (map, x) => {
            if (!map.dict.hasOwnProperty(x.artist.id)) {
                map.raw.push(map.dict[x.artist.id] = {...x.artist, content:[]});
            }
            map.dict[x.artist.id].content.push({id: x.id, name: x.name});
            return map;
        },
        {dict:{},raw:[]}
    )
    .raw

);
```

Напрашивается ещё проверка дубликатов по идентификатору мелодии, думаю сам разберёшься как её добавить.

Comment: В исходных данных дубликатов нет.

Comment: это ты сейчас так думаешь

Comment: @norbornen таких талантов только плюсовать надо +от меня

Comment: @norbornen Я бэкендер, там никогда не будет дубликатов :)